Problemas com o meu codigo visual studio
Boa tarde!
Estou iniciando no HTML5 e CSS3 e estou com problema com um código.
Meu código function com a atribuição document.getElementById não funciona, é como se ele não reconhecesse o comando. Nenhuma das funções de mouse funcionam no site, eu fiz algo errado ou tais comandos não são mais utilizados?
Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?
imagem do código no Visual Studio

O seu código deveria estar funcionando de acordo com a imagem que foi fornecida, mas para o seu caso em específico em relação ao resultado exclusivo da imagem, sem o "código completo" e o ambiente onde está sendo executado, podem haver restrições ou problemas que estão impedindo o funcionamento. Sem informações adicionais, não podemos oferecer uma solução precisa.

muito obrigado @leensc
